# toggle cell height when selecting cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

in my .h file

```
    NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath;
```

in my .m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;  
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; 
}  

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    if(selectedCellIndexPath != nil && [selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame){
        return 80;  
    } else if ([selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] != NSOrderedSame){
    return 40;
    }

    return 40;  
}
```

with this code, I'm able to expand the cell height when tapped on, however I'm having trouble making it collapse

Comment: When you want to collapse cell?

Comment: @vienvu when you tap an expanded cell, sort of a toggle if you will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `selectedCellIndexPath` back to nil when the user selects an expanded cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedCellIndexPath = (self.selectedCellIndexPath && [self.selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame) ? nil : indexPath;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: code works but would you mind explaining this snippet for me, its syntax i haven't seen before, specifically the question mark.     NSOrderedSame) ? nil : indexPath;

Comment: That is a ternary operator. The syntax is `let x = a ? b : c`. `a` is a boolean value. If `a == true` then `x = b`, if `a == false` then `x = c`

Comment: In other word it is the same as writing `if a { x = b } else { x = c }`

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you!